# Scrapy with Selenium only crawling to first site instead of multiple sites

Tags: selenium, scrapy

I am currently scraping data which are generated by javascript in a website. Thus, i am using scrapy and selenium for scraping such data. However, the spider is only able to crawl and scrape data from the first site. Any one can help me on this? Below is the code that i have written. Thanks in advance.

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.http import Request
import time
from selenium import webdriver

class w01item(scrapy.Item):
    date = scrapy.Field()
    title = scrapy.Field()
    underlying_bid = scrapy.Field()
    bid = scrapy.Field()

class mqSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "w11"
    allowed_domains = ["kswarrants.kasikornsecurities.com"]
    start_urls = ["http://kswarrants.kasikornsecurities.com/www/Tool/calculator"]
    def __init__(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()

    def parse(self, response):
        self.driver.get(response.url)
        self.driver.add_cookie({'name':'Disc', 'value':'YES','path':'/'})
        self.driver.get("http://kswarrants.kasikornsecurities.com/www/Tool/calculator")
        options=self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//select[@id="underling0"]/option')
        for option in options[1:4]:
            a = option.text
            textbox=self.driver.find_element_by_id("calid")
            textbox.send_keys(option.text)
            time.sleep(1)
            self.driver.find_element_by_id("btn_sub").click()
            time.sleep(2)
            for x in xrange(1,3):
                item = w01item()
                item['title']= a
                item['date'] = self.driver.find_element_by_id('d_1').text
                item['underlying_bid']= self.driver.find_element_by_id('d_'+ str(x)+'_1').text
                item['bid'] = self.driver.find_element_by_id('d_'+ str(x)+'_2').text
                yield item
            self.driver.find_element_by_id("calid").clear()
```

The log from running the script is below.

```
2016-03-21 23:14:56 [scrapy] INFO: Scrapy 1.0.5 started (bot: scrapybot)
2016-03-21 23:14:56 [scrapy] INFO: Optional features available: ssl, http11
2016-03-21 23:14:56 [scrapy] INFO: Overridden settings: {}
2016-03-21 23:14:56 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled extensions: CloseSpider, TelnetConsole, LogStats, CoreStats, SpiderState
2016-03-21 23:15:02 [selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection] DEBUG: POST http://127.0.0.1:55653/hub/session {"desiredCapabilities": {"platform": "ANY", "br
: "firefox", "version": "", "marionette": false, "javascriptEnabled": true}}
2016-03-21 23:15:02 [selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection] DEBUG: Finished Request
2016-03-21 23:15:02 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares: HttpAuthMiddleware, DownloadTimeoutMiddleware, UserAgentMiddleware, RetryMiddleware, DefaultH
leware, MetaRefreshMiddleware, HttpCompressionMiddleware, RedirectMiddleware, CookiesMiddleware, ChunkedTransferMiddleware, DownloaderStats
2016-03-21 23:15:02 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares: HttpErrorMiddleware, OffsiteMiddleware, RefererMiddleware, UrlLengthMiddleware, DepthMiddleware
2016-03-21 23:15:02 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
2016-03-21 23:15:02 [scrapy] INFO: Spider opened
2016-03-21 23:15:02 [scrapy] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2016-03-21 23:15:02 [scrapy] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2016-03-21 23:15:02 [scrapy] DEBUG: Redirecting (302) to <GET http://kswarrants.kasikornsecurities.com/www/Tool/Disc?rurl=calculator> from <GET http://kswarrant
securities.com/www/Tool/calculator>
2016-03-21 23:15:02 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://kswarrants.kasikornsecurities.com/www/Tool/Disc?rurl=calculator> (referer: None)
2016-03-21 23:15:03 [selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection] DEBUG: POST http://127.0.0.1:55653/hub/session/415890c0-fdaa-4c41-80a5-1334d1d5ac8a/url {"url"
kswarrants.kasikornsecurities.com/www/Tool/Disc?rurl=calculator", "sessionId": "415890c0-fdaa-4c41-80a5-1334d1d5ac8a"}
2016-03-21 23:15:04 [selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection] DEBUG: Finished Request
2016-03-21 23:15:04 [selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection] DEBUG: POST http://127.0.0.1:55653/hub/session/415890c0-fdaa-4c41-80a5-1334d1d5ac8a/cookie {"s
 "415890c0-fdaa-4c41-80a5-1334d1d5ac8a", "cookie": {"path": "/", "name": "Disc", "value": "YES"}}
2016-03-21 23:15:04 [selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection] DEBUG: Finished Request
2016-03-21 23:15:04 [selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection] DEBUG: POST http://127.0.0.1:55653/hub/session/415890c0-fdaa-4c41-80a5-1334d1d5ac8a/url {"url"
kswarrants.kasikornsecurities.com/www/Tool/calculator", "sessionId": "415890c0-fdaa-4c41-80a5-1334d1d5ac8a"}
2016-03-21 23:15:05 [selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection] DEBUG: Finished Request
2016-03-21 23:15:05 [selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection] DEBUG: POST http://127.0.0.1:55653/hub/session/415890c0-fdaa-4c41-80a5-1334d1d5ac8a/elements {
xpath", "sessionId": "415890c0-fdaa-4c41-80a5-1334d1d5ac8a", "value": "//select[@id=\"underling0\"]/option"}
2016-03-21 23:15:05 [selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection] DEBUG: Finished Request
2016-03-21 23:15:05 [selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection] DEBUG: GET http://127.0.0.1:55653/hub/session/415890c0-fdaa-4c41-80a5-1334d1d5ac8a/element/{06
2-46ee-9e2c-720482b405d8}/text {"sessionId": "415890c0-fdaa-4c41-80a5-1334d1d5ac8a", "id": "{06d323c4-f252-46ee-9e2c-720482b405d8}"}
2016-03-21 23:15:05 [selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection] DEBUG: Finished Request
2016-03-21 23:15:05 [selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection] DEBUG: POST http://127.0.0.1:55653/hub/session/415890c0-fdaa-4c41-80a5-1334d1d5ac8a/element {"
d", "sessionId": "415890c0-fdaa-4c41-80a5-1334d1d5ac8a", "value": "calid"}
2016-03-21 23:15:05 [selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection] DEBUG: Finished Request
2016-03-21 23:15:05 [selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection] DEBUG: GET http://127.0.0.1:55653/hub/session/415890c0-fdaa-4c41-80a5-1334d1d5ac8a/element/{06
2-46ee-9e2c-720482b405d8}/text {"sessionId": "415890c0-fdaa-4c41-80a5-1334d1d5ac8a", "id": "{06d323c4-f252-46ee-9e2c-720482b405d8}"}
2016-03-21 23:15:05 [selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection] DEBUG: Finished Request
2016-03-21 23:15:05 [selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection] DEBUG: POST http://127.0.0.1:55653/hub/session/415890c0-fdaa-4c41-80a5-1334d1d5ac8a/element/{a
62-4578-896c-9de40ce48162}/value {"sessionId": "415890c0-fdaa-4c41-80a5-1334d1d5ac8a", "id": "{a06dc4f5-0462-4578-896c-9de40ce48162}", "value": ["A", "A", "V",
"C", "1", "6", "0", "4", "A"]}
2016-03-21 23:15:06 [selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection] DEBUG: Finished Request
2016-03-21 23:15:07 [selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection] DEBUG: POST http://127.0.0.1:55653/hub/session/415890c0-fdaa-4c41-80a5-1334d1d5ac8a/element {"
d", "sessionId": "415890c0-fdaa-4c41-80a5-1334d1d5ac8a", "value": "btn_sub"}
2016-03-21 23:15:07 [selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection] DEBUG: Finished Request
2016-03-21 23:15:07 [selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection] DEBUG: POST http://127.0.0.1:55653/hub/session/415890c0-fdaa-4c41-80a5-1334d1d5ac8a/element/{e
ae-4848-9bac-450b5567842b}/click {"sessionId": "415890c0-fdaa-4c41-80a5-1334d1d5ac8a", "id": "{ee24c112-f7ae-4848-9bac-450b5567842b}"}
2016-03-21 23:15:08 [selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection] DEBUG: Finished Request
2016-03-21 23:15:10 [selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection] DEBUG: POST http://127.0.0.1:55653/hub/session/415890c0-fdaa-4c41-80a5-1334d1d5ac8a/element {"
d", "sessionId": "415890c0-fdaa-4c41-80a5-1334d1d5ac8a", "value": "d_1"}
2016-03-21 23:15:10 [selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection] DEBUG: Finished Request
2016-03-21 23:15:10 [selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection] DEBUG: GET http://127.0.0.1:55653/hub/session/415890c0-fdaa-4c41-80a5-1334d1d5ac8a/element/{74
0-45be-80bb-152e3cc78c6a}/text {"sessionId": "415890c0-fdaa-4c41-80a5-1334d1d5ac8a", "id": "{741d6ad8-2640-45be-80bb-152e3cc78c6a}"}
2016-03-21 23:15:10 [selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection] DEBUG: Finished Request
2016-03-21 23:15:10 [selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection] DEBUG: POST http://127.0.0.1:55653/hub/session/415890c0-fdaa-4c41-80a5-1334d1d5ac8a/element {"
d", "sessionId": "415890c0-fdaa-4c41-80a5-1334d1d5ac8a", "value": "d_1_1"}
2016-03-21 23:15:10 [selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection] DEBUG: Finished Request
2016-03-21 23:15:10 [selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection] DEBUG: GET http://127.0.0.1:55653/hub/session/415890c0-fdaa-4c41-80a5-1334d1d5ac8a/element/{d2
1-48bc-a76e-fccc5ad9e646}/text {"sessionId": "415890c0-fdaa-4c41-80a5-1334d1d5ac8a", "id": "{d25a795f-4721-48bc-a76e-fccc5ad9e646}"}
2016-03-21 23:15:10 [selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection] DEBUG: Finished Request
2016-03-21 23:15:10 [selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection] DEBUG: POST http://127.0.0.1:55653/hub/session/415890c0-fdaa-4c41-80a5-1334d1d5ac8a/element {"
d", "sessionId": "415890c0-fdaa-4c41-80a5-1334d1d5ac8a", "value": "d_1_2"}
2016-03-21 23:15:10 [selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection] DEBUG: Finished Request
2016-03-21 23:15:10 [selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection] DEBUG: GET http://127.0.0.1:55653/hub/session/415890c0-fdaa-4c41-80a5-1334d1d5ac8a/element/{3d
b-40a0-8880-9f5675bed655}/text {"sessionId": "415890c0-fdaa-4c41-80a5-1334d1d5ac8a", "id": "{3d380c09-248b-40a0-8880-9f5675bed655}"}
2016-03-21 23:15:10 [selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection] DEBUG: Finished Request
2016-03-21 23:15:10 [scrapy] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://kswarrants.kasikornsecurities.com/www/Tool/Disc?rurl=calculator>
{'bid': u'0.77',
 'date': u'21/03/2016',
 'title': u'AAV11C1604A',
 'underlying_bid': u'5.10'}
2016-03-21 23:15:10 [selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection] DEBUG: POST http://127.0.0.1:55653/hub/session/415890c0-fdaa-4c41-80a5-1334d1d5ac8a/element {"
d", "sessionId": "415890c0-fdaa-4c41-80a5-1334d1d5ac8a", "value": "d_1"}
2016-03-21 23:15:10 [selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection] DEBUG: Finished Request
2016-03-21 23:15:10 [selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection] DEBUG: GET http://127.0.0.1:55653/hub/session/415890c0-fdaa-4c41-80a5-1334d1d5ac8a/element/{74
0-45be-80bb-152e3cc78c6a}/text {"sessionId": "415890c0-fdaa-4c41-80a5-1334d1d5ac8a", "id": "{741d6ad8-2640-45be-80bb-152e3cc78c6a}"}
2016-03-21 23:15:10 [selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection] DEBUG: Finished Request
2016-03-21 23:15:10 [selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection] DEBUG: POST http://127.0.0.1:55653/hub/session/415890c0-fdaa-4c41-80a5-1334d1d5ac8a/element {"
d", "sessionId": "415890c0-fdaa-4c41-80a5-1334d1d5ac8a", "value": "d_2_1"}
2016-03-21 23:15:10 [selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection] DEBUG: Finished Request
2016-03-21 23:15:10 [selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection] DEBUG: GET http://127.0.0.1:55653/hub/session/415890c0-fdaa-4c41-80a5-1334d1d5ac8a/element/{60
8-4302-93dc-079c6e686055}/text {"sessionId": "415890c0-fdaa-4c41-80a5-1334d1d5ac8a", "id": "{606f3c95-5e98-4302-93dc-079c6e686055}"}
2016-03-21 23:15:10 [selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection] DEBUG: Finished Request
2016-03-21 23:15:10 [selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection] DEBUG: POST http://127.0.0.1:55653/hub/session/415890c0-fdaa-4c41-80a5-1334d1d5ac8a/element {"
d", "sessionId": "415890c0-fdaa-4c41-80a5-1334d1d5ac8a", "value": "d_2_2"}
2016-03-21 23:15:10 [selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection] DEBUG: Finished Request
2016-03-21 23:15:10 [selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection] DEBUG: GET http://127.0.0.1:55653/hub/session/415890c0-fdaa-4c41-80a5-1334d1d5ac8a/element/{8b
0-461f-aafe-0bdafa2c6d6f}/text {"sessionId": "415890c0-fdaa-4c41-80a5-1334d1d5ac8a", "id": "{8be98315-46d0-461f-aafe-0bdafa2c6d6f}"}
2016-03-21 23:15:10 [selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection] DEBUG: Finished Request
2016-03-21 23:15:10 [scrapy] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://kswarrants.kasikornsecurities.com/www/Tool/Disc?rurl=calculator>
{'bid': u'0.80',
 'date': u'21/03/2016',
 'title': u'AAV11C1604A',
 'underlying_bid': u'5.15'}
2016-03-21 23:15:10 [selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection] DEBUG: POST http://127.0.0.1:55653/hub/session/415890c0-fdaa-4c41-80a5-1334d1d5ac8a/element {"
d", "sessionId": "415890c0-fdaa-4c41-80a5-1334d1d5ac8a", "value": "calid"}
2016-03-21 23:15:10 [selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection] DEBUG: Finished Request
2016-03-21 23:15:10 [selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection] DEBUG: POST http://127.0.0.1:55653/hub/session/415890c0-fdaa-4c41-80a5-1334d1d5ac8a/element/{9
70-408c-b683-5c363412cf0f}/clear {"sessionId": "415890c0-fdaa-4c41-80a5-1334d1d5ac8a", "id": "{9c1a9c4b-aa70-408c-b683-5c363412cf0f}"}
2016-03-21 23:15:11 [selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection] DEBUG: Finished Request
2016-03-21 23:15:11 [selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection] DEBUG: GET http://127.0.0.1:55653/hub/session/415890c0-fdaa-4c41-80a5-1334d1d5ac8a/element/{00
7-4a5b-86c9-96bed980ebef}/text {"sessionId": "415890c0-fdaa-4c41-80a5-1334d1d5ac8a", "id": "{001d727c-3f87-4a5b-86c9-96bed980ebef}"}
2016-03-21 23:15:12 [selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection] DEBUG: Finished Request
2016-03-21 23:15:12 [scrapy] ERROR: Spider error processing <GET http://kswarrants.kasikornsecurities.com/www/Tool/Disc?rurl=calculator> (referer: None)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy\utils\defer.py", line 102, in iter_errback
    yield next(it)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spidermiddlewares\offsite.py", line 28, in process_spider_output
    for x in result:
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spidermiddlewares\referer.py", line 22, in <genexpr>
    return (_set_referer(r) for r in result or ())
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spidermiddlewares\urllength.py", line 37, in <genexpr>
    return (r for r in result or () if _filter(r))
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spidermiddlewares\depth.py", line 54, in <genexpr>
    return (r for r in result or () if _filter(r))
  File "D:\testing\w11s.py", line 25, in parse
    a = option.text
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 70, in text
    return self._execute(Command.GET_ELEMENT_TEXT)['value']
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 457, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 233, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 194, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
StaleElementReferenceException: Message: Element not found in the cache - perhaps the page has changed since it was looked up
Stacktrace:
    at fxdriver.cache.getElementAt (resource://fxdriver/modules/web-element-cache.js:9454)
    at Utils.getElementAt (file:///d:/ssd/tempfi~1/tmpzt51xr/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:9039)
    at WebElement.getElementText (file:///d:/ssd/tempfi~1/tmpzt51xr/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12092)
    at DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_/h (file:///d:/ssd/tempfi~1/tmpzt51xr/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12661)
    at DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_ (file:///d:/ssd/tempfi~1/tmpzt51xr/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12666)
    at DelayedCommand.prototype.execute/< (file:///d:/ssd/tempfi~1/tmpzt51xr/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12608)
2016-03-21 23:15:12 [scrapy] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
```

Comment: you are overriding the constructor without calling the parent's constructor too

Comment: sorry. i do not understand what you are saying as i am still quite new to scrapy and selenium. I just picked it up 2 - 3 weeks ago. Can you give an example? Thanks

Comment: There's only one driver.get call so only one page is fetched. Can you explain what pages you want to scrape, the website you're looking at won't render in english on my machine.

Comment: The page i want to scrape is http://kswarrants.kasikornsecurities.com/www/Tool/calculator You have to click the UK flag on the top right corner so that the website is rendered in english. The data can be found when the option is filled. An example is AAV11C1604A. Upon submitting the option, values will be generated in a table below (Price Guideline: Simulation Date). These are the values that i want to scrape. There are about 100 options in total.

Answer (score 0):

You should `yield Requet` to the scrapy scheduler if you'd like to follow the links.

See: http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html#following-links